# what will be the alert when I have same name for a variable and function?

Tags: javascript

```
var test = 100;

function test(){

var i=0;

}

alert(test);
```

Can you please test this and let me know what will be the priority for variable and function name?

After testing above please try with commenting the 1st line `// var test = 100;`
and check what is the output.

I just want to know why this happened?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? If so, I assume you have a specific question in mind, so please ask your question more directly.

Comment: the javascript console is a great way to answer questions like this.

Comment: I have tested but just want to know the priority of variable and function...
As when you make comment the 1st line you will get the whole function get alert...
please try again and let me know why this happened

Comment: Pardon my terminology abuse, but I think something like this is happening:

Non-anonymous functions are declared during static analysis and "pulled to the top" of the code. So the last definition `test` is the valid one.

Answer (score 0):

It outputs 100. I assume because you're `alert()` the `test` variable, not the `test()` function

I ran a fiddle on it..

[jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/Mdgr2/)

Comment: thanks for response... But if you make comment for the variable then it will alert the whole function... Can you please try once again

Comment: Of course. It was quite easy, next time try it yourself. You're prolly gonna get downvoted because of it though :( Sorry (I wont)

Comment: I just alert test but why it alert the whole function?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the function name same as your variable name.
if you first define a variable and then function, the variable with override with the function.

```
function test(){

alert(3);

}
```

is same as

```
var test=function() {alert(3)};
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the variable scope it will go for function scope value i=0 if you want to call function u need to call test() out side with return value then only it will pick up the value from scoped variables.

```
var test = 100;
function test(){
var i=0;
return i;
}
alert(test());
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, let's see how javascript handles the following code:

```
var test = 100;

function test(){

var i=0;

}

alert(test);
```

With [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting), this is how the JS parser will transform your code:

```
// Variables & functions declarations are hoisted
var test;
function test() {
    var i = 0;
}

// Then the actual code is run. Thus, your assignment.
test = 100;

alert(test);
```

I guess you now understand why it alerts 100.